# MySQL: user has pets, petnames of one user should be unique but other users can name their pets like other users

Tags: mysql, sql, database

So I have two tables: user and pet
the user uses the unique username as a primary key
the pet should use their petname + username together as a primary key, so that one user can't name two of their pets equally, but another user can name his pet like the pet of another user.

I have already tried to put the username and the petname as unique. But that way the petname can only be used once for the whole table.

Comment: Sorry but would you mind rephrasing the question please. Also it would be really helpful to have sample data in the question plus the output you are expecting.

Answer (score 0):

```sql
CREATE TABLE user (username VARCHAR(255) PRIMARY KEY);

CREATE TABLE pet (username VARCHAR(255),
                  petname VARCHAR(255),
                  PRIMARY KEY (username, petname),
                  FOREIGN KEY (username) REFERENCES user (username));
```

https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=526cdc3ad91b450448b34dc9a6d006f1